# Google Sheets remove duplicates from a comma separated cell and count how many times that value is seen for each person?

Tags: google-sheets

So I have this [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A5LMN-WFsGN-4y3yOB1TFsnAY7ms5z8sM7AtpiQTlac/edit#gid=0) and this formula so far.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((B2:B<>"")*(C2:C<>""), SUBSTITUTE(B2:B&", "&C2:C, ", ", ","), IF(B2:B<>"", B2:B, C2:C)))`

In Sheet 1, Column A is a list of names. I have combined the values of B and C but I need to filter out duplicates for each row.

The end result is like Sheet 2 where each instance of the Tags are counted for each person. On sheet 2, it's okay to have duplicates because I need the record count.

Is there a better way to approach this? Can this be simplified with a formula?

Any help or insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options:

For the first D column, you can use TEXTJOIN and MAP:

```
=MAP(B2:B,C2:C,LAMBDA(b,c,TEXTJOIN(",",1,b,c)))
```

For E column, you can use TRIMP and SPLIT to divide and remove spaces, and use BYROW with UNIQUE to filter out the duplicates in each row:

```
=BYROW(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TRIM(SPLIT(D2:D,",",1,1)))),LAMBDA(a,UNIQUE(a,1)))
```

In fact, you could just remove column D and use:

[image]
=BYROW(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TRIM(SPLIT(MAP(B2:B,C2:C,LAMBDA(b,c,TEXTJOIN(",",1,b,c))),",",1,1)))),LAMBDA(a,UNIQUE(a,1)))

For the other chart, you can use LET to calculate the different values:

```
=LET(names,TOROW(UNIQUE(Sheet1!A2:A),1),
tagss,UNIQUE(TOCOL(Sheet1!E2:Z,1)),
tags,FILTER(tagss,tagss<>""),
VSTACK(HSTACK("HEADER",names),
HSTACK(tags,MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(tags),COUNTA(names),LAMBDA(r,c,COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!A2:A=INDEX(names,,c),BYROW(Sheet1!E2:Z,LAMBDA(e,IFNA(XMATCH(INDEX(tags,r),e))))))))))))
```

Here it goes with comments:

```
=LET(names,TOROW(UNIQUE(Sheet1!A2:A),1), --> finds the names
tagss,UNIQUE(TOCOL(Sheet1!E2:Z,1)), --> finds the tags
tags,FILTER(tagss,tagss<>""), --> and filters some empty values that remained... with TOCOL(...,1) it should have worked, but it didn't
VSTACK(HSTACK("HEADER",names), --> now, I'm stacking the header, with the names
HSTACK(tags,MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(tags),COUNTA(names),LAMBDA(r,c,COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!A2:A=INDEX(names,,c),BYROW(Sheet1!E2:Z,LAMBDA(e,IFNA(XMATCH(INDEX(tags,r),e))))))))))))  --> and here I'm stacking horizontally the tags in vertical, and making an array, that uses COUNTA and FILTER to filter out the values in Sheet!A2:A, based on the names and if the tag is matched within each row
```

[image]

Comment: looks like it's what I needed, thanks. I would have never come up with these formulas myself. I ended up having to use D, as without it some rows were skipped if B was empty.

Comment: followup question, say I had Sheet 3 and I wanted to count only the No's, would the same logic / formula work?

Comment: You need to count the amount of No's per person in a similar structure of several values per row? You should use something similar, yes. Try deleting second line, and changing third one to `tags,"No",`

Comment: Oh, and I didn't tell you before, but if you prefer no to use all those extra columns, you can just replace Sheets!E2:Z inside of the last formula with the MAP formula, and do everything in one cell

Comment: Sorry I wasn't that clear on the expected result, I put the expected result on Sheet 4. I'm trying to count how many times each of those parameters on Column A gets a "No" answer. Column A does not change or is fixed.

Comment: I suggest you to upload a new question. Please add as far as you've got by yourself, and post the link here if you want, so I can refer quickly to it ;)